# Problems with ecoreg in R

Tags: r, regression, hierarchical

I want to perform research on combining individual and aggregated data with a hierarchical related regression. Therefore, I wanted to use the package ecoreg.

Below is the code and a summary of the data I insert.

```
pDV       n       pIV
0.02974330  17920   0.02779018
0.02843174  13295   0.02564874
0.02761653  11370   0.02515391
0.01849075  10005   0.01589205
0.02738854  7850    0.02267516
0.02488095  8400    0.01904762
0.02459336  7685    0.02121015
0.02352941  6375    0.01866667
0.02079295  5675    0.01797357

eco(cbind(pDV, n) ~ pIV, data = agg)
```

However I keep getting the same error message.

> Error in checkdata(X, Y, supplement, ndim) : 
>     Values of X and Y have to be between 0 and 1.

All my values are between 0 and 1, except `n`. However, in the ecoreg file they also use n with values above 1 and are able to get a correct output. If I remove the `n`. I am able to get output, only then I do not get the output I want, for example:

```
Call:
eco(formula = cbind(pIV) ~ pDV, data = agg)
Aggregate In-sample Estimates:

                       W1        W2      
posterior mean  0.948122  0.008483
```

Instead, I would like to have the same output as Jackson has in the ecoreg file. Namely, with odds ratios and log-likelihood:

```
eco(cbind(disease, n) ~ p.smoke, data = agg)
Call:
eco(formula = cbind(disease, n) ~ p.smoke, data = agg)
Aggregate-level odds ratios:
              OR l95  u95
(Intercept) 0.31 0.3 0.32
p.smoke     3.61 2.7 4.74
No individual-level covariates
-2 x log-likelihood:  2141
```

So I would like to have similar output as above and I do not understand why the `n` gives troubles in my console, but it seems to work in the ecoreg guide.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. It would be of great help! You can find the guide of ecoreg here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecoreg/vignettes/ecoreg-guide.pdf